# Storyboard view controller leaks

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, uistoryboard, instruments

I'm having leaks and I can't figure out how to fix them. You'll find below the Instruments screenshot.

[image]

And that's the piece of code triggering most of them.

[image]

Is there any other way to instantiate a view controller that wouldn't create leaks?

Comment: How about showing some code from your view controller initialization logic?

Comment: Leaking or just sticking around? You are creating two references to vc in your code. One is released when popping, the self.pushedViewController however will remain.

Comment: Yes, the `pushedViewController` property might be the issue. Is that ever being reset or cleared? Do you even need it? You can always ask the navigation controller to return the view controller at the top of the stack.

Comment: @rob5408 I tried with and without this variable, leak is still there.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you posted that should cause a leak when using ARC. Perhaps its something in the pushed view controller itself?

Comment: @rdelmar I think so too. Although the storyboard line leaking is the one I don't understand. Any pointers on that?

Comment: No, I've never seen a leak on that kind of statement. I'm not that experienced at using the Leaks instrument, so I don't know what it is you're seeing in that trace.

Answer (score 0):

You should check what are you actually leaking - generation analysis is a good start.

My guess is that UIKit might leak some strings and dictionaries which, in my experience, somewhat expected when using nibs or storyboards.